# List of dictionaries: Merge, sort, and pick top (n) entries

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
list_of_dicts = [
    {'item1': 100}, 
    {'item2': 2405},
    {'item3': 884},
    ....
]
```

What I'm doing:

```
from collections import ChainMap
import heapq
from operator import itemgetter

merged_map = ChainMap(*list_of_dicts)       
merged_dict = dict(merged_map)

# Pick the 2 entries with largest *value*
heap = heapq.nlargest(2, merged_dict.items(), key=itemgetter(1))

# Convert result list to a dict
....
```

Is there a more efficient/elegant way of doing the above?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i know this is as efficient as your `heapq`-approach but with slightly less code:

```
from collections import Counter, ChainMap

list_of_dicts = [
    {'item1': 100},
    {'item2': 2405},
    {'item3': 884},
]

counter = Counter(ChainMap(*list_of_dicts))
res = dict(counter.most_common(2))
print(res)  # {'item2': 2405, 'item3': 884}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks much better. But there is the extra step of converting the result from a list of tuples to a dict. I'm running this code in a loop millions of times. Do you think we can do better?

Comment: so the result here should be ` {'item2': 2405, 'item3': 884}`?

Comment: Yes. A single dictionary.

Comment: i guess now it is a question of benchmarking which version works best for you. maybe also give pandas a try: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html